# Как пронумеровать символы в строке?

Tags: python, строки, функции

```
s = 'Hello, my name is John.\nI love pizza.\n' 
r = s.count('\n') 
r= str(r) 
s = s.replace('\n',r)
print(s)
```

Написал вот такой код, для заметы пробелов, но нехватает одного, нужно чтобы не просто колличество выводилось символов, а номер этих самых символов. Как это сделать?

Comment: А где у вас работа с пробелами вообще?

Comment: Ну, я имел в виду с переносом строк, не то написал)

Comment: Покажите пример, какой должен быть результат

Comment: "Hello, my name is John.<1>I love pizza.<2>"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

как вариант:

```
s = 'Hello, my name is John.\nI love pizza.\n' 

r = [f'<{i}>' for i in range(1,s.count('\n')+1)] 
res = s.replace('\n', '{}').format(*r)

>>> res
'Hello, my name is John.<1>I love pizza.<2>'
```

Comment: Спасибо, но я уже проголосовал. Не менять же)

Answer (score 2):

Я так понимаю, вы хотите заменить переносы строк на их номер. Тогда в методе replace, указывайте третий параметр, это количество заменяемых вхождений. И в цикле по одному меняйте

```
s = 'Hello, my name is John.\nI love pizza.\n' 
r = s.count('\n') 
for i in range(r):
    s = s.replace('\n',str(i + 1), 1)
print(s)
```

Результат:

```
Hello, my name is John.1I love pizza.2
```

Comment: Спасибо, это именно то что я и хотел)

Comment: @MaxIst Пожалуйста:) И не забудьте принять ответ